# Understanding probability density functions.

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

This is a very basic question but I was hoping you could all clarify.

If we have a probability density function $f(x)$ and we want to find, say $P(X = 1)$, we would find the area under the curve where $x = 1$, which is $0$.

However, if we consider the case of a Bernoulli distributed random variable where $P(X = 1)$ is $1/2$, and we know that the PDF of the Bernoulli distribution is $p^x(1-p)^{1-x}$, how would we possibly get the result that $P(X=1)$ is $1/2$ if we think in terms of the definite integral?

Comment: See the Riemann Stieltjes integral or Lebesgue (Stieltjes) integral. These notes look at probability using Riemann Stieltjes integral: https://www.stat.rice.edu/~dobelman/notes_papers/math/riemannstieltjes.pdf

Comment: For what it's worth, it is debatable whether giving the effort to read these notes is truly worthwhile. If you would rather just read about Lebesgue integral, which is what everyone uses, then https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf or any probability text.

Comment: In the first case, you are dealing with a continuous random variable, and in the second case a discrete random variable. Perhaps, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Examples) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_or_discrete_variable) might help.

Comment: Continuous versus discrete random RVs. The set $\{1\}$ is of measure zero in the continuum but is of positive measure in the natural numbers under the usual Lesbesgue measure.